# Bootstrap, jumbotron and sticky footer

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I have a jumbotron on my front page, and it works great. I have a sticky footer, and it works great as well. Until I put them together. The wrap class ruins the jumbotron, but taking it out ruins the footer. The content gets lost in the mess somewhere in there too. Obviously, with the jumbotron i don't technically need the footer to stick to the bottom since the jumbotron will push it to the bottom, but I need it for the other pages that don't have the jumbotron.

Also, before anyone tries to answer with a fixed footer, that's not at all what I'm looking for.

[jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qss9469m/1/)

---

```
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .wrap {
            min-height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .footer {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top:-150px;
            height: 150px;
            background: orange;
        }

        .jumbotron {
            background-color: inherit;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .container-full-bg {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
            background-color: red;
        }

            .container-full-bg .container, .container-full-bg .container .jumbotron {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
```

---

```
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="container-full-bg">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">my jumbotron</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>
content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div><!--/wrap-->

    <div class="footer">my footer</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've ended up with...

Since I'm using Wordpress I decided to, even though I don't want to, check if we're on the front page or not, and add the necessary stylesheets and divs where needed:

added to header.php in the head of the document.

```
<?php
if(!is_front_page()) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'
    . get_template_directory_uri() . '/stickyfooter.css" />';
} ?>


...
```

then, I add the wrap if we're not on the front page

```
<?php if(!is_front_page()){
    //wrap the content only if we're not on the front page.
    //this is to push the sticky footer down.
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
}

?>


...
```

and in footer.php i close the wrap div before the actual footer

---

stickyfooter.css:

```
.wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -246px;
}

.wrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height:246px;
}

 .footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 246px;
    margin-top: -246px;
 }
```

So there you have it. I supply the pages with the code they prefer depending on their layout.